# Passing value from one component to another

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

How to pass values from one component to another component through service or any other way, when components are not parent to child or child to parent?

Answer (score -1):

You can user a `service` to pass datas from a component to an other.

`data.service.ts` :

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
   private data: string;

   constructor() {
      this.data = 'myData'
   }

   getData(): Promise<string> {
     return Promise.resolve(this.data);
   }

   setData(data: string) {
      this.data = data;
   } 
}
```

`component A` :

```
export class ComponentA {

   private data: string;
   constructor(private dataService: dataService) {
      this.getData();
   }

   getData() {
     this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
       (data) => {
         this.data = data;
       }
     )
   }

   setData(data: string) {
     this.dataService.setData(data);
   }
}
```

`component B` :

```
export class ComponentB {

   private data: string;
   constructor(private dataService: dataService) {
      this.getData();
   }

   getData() {
     this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
       (data) => {
         this.data = data;
       }
     )
   }

   setData(data: string) {
     this.dataService.setData(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Service doesn't need any annotation.

Comment: This annotation says that THIS class can inject something in constructor. It's not common to get this class in any other classes (ie components).

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectable That decorator makes it possible for Angular to identify the types of its two dependencies, LoggerService and UserService.